# Prove: If every compact subset of (M,d) is finite then (M,d) is homeomorphic to (M,discrete)

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis

I am running into issues proving that:

---

If every compact subset of (M,d) is finite then (M,d) is homeomorphic to (M,discrete)

---

I can understand that if M itself is compact and finite then the proof follows, but I can't seem to show this.

Am I approaching this in the wrong way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HINT: Suppose that $\langle M,d\rangle$ is not discrete, and let $p\in M$ be a non-isolated point. By considering the nbhds $B_d\left(p,\frac1n\right)$ for $n\in\Bbb Z^+$, recursively construct a sequence $\langle x_n:n\in\Bbb Z^+\rangle$ in $M\setminus\{p\}$ that converges to $p$. Use this sequence to construct an infinite compact subset of $M$.